# How do I incorporate fluid width video with Parallax website?

Tags: javascript, css, video, parallax, fluid-layout

I have a basic Parallax website [**here**](http://davidgumzchoi.github.io/Parallax/), but when I try to add a dynamic embedded youtube video I get an error. A fluid width video is explained [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

```
<section id="youtube" class="bg_parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CsaL_BDAeqA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
<section id="home" class="bg_parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="20"></section>
<section id="about" class="bg_parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="40"></section>
<section id="blog" class="bg_parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="80"></section>
<section id="contact" class="bg_parallax" data-type="background" data-speed="160"></section>
```

I'm trying to maintain my Parallax functionality, while having a fluid width video, but I have that strange white space on the bottom. I think the problem may be somewhere in my CSS, but all the attributes are very specific for the parallax effect to work properly.

```
#youtube {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

#youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And this is my jQuery that allows for parallax scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $objWindow = $(window);
    $('div[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgObj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($objWindow.scrollTop() / $bgObj.data('speed')); 
            var coords = '100% '+ yPos + 'px';
            // Animate the background
            $bgObj.css({backgroundPosition:coords});
        });
    });
});
```

There are hack-y solutions that I can come up with, but is there something wrong with my JS or CSS that I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the images disappear as you change your browser window width.

That issue aside, have you tried applying a relative position to your YouTube section? i.e.

```
#youtube {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative; /* All your other <section> blocks use this */
}
```

Comment: thanks i think this seemed to resolve the issue! `#youtube {height: 100%; position: relative;} #youtube iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%;}`